# The page at [Page URL] could not be reached

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to add the like button on my website, but it does not work because whenever I click on Like button it says:

> The page at could not be reached.

You can also check the URL to see the error: 
[My Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Alexa-Beauty/205401152839187)

Here is what I did to use the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
  <meta property="og:title" content="ALEXA BEAUTY" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="company" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://alexasalon.co.uk/" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://alexasalon.co.uk/images/logo.png" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="ALEXA BEAUTY" />
  <meta property="fb:admins" content="100002556535323" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=220687968005095";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div>
  <fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Alexa-Beauty/205401152839187" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false" font="lucida grande"></fb:like>
</div>
```

Is the code wrong? Is the page URL correct?
I checked the website on Object Debugger and seems there is no error, check [link](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.alexasalon.co.uk) please.

I really do not know what is wrong? Does anyone know?

Comment: Are you sure that you have *published* the page and it's not *private*?

Comment: Check this: http://www.jacobv.com/technology/page-could-not-be-found-error-with-facebook-like-button/

Comment: No it is published, you can also check: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Alexa-Beauty/205401152839187

BUT is there anything I need to change on the page, like insight or anything to link the page to the website ???

Comment: Check the page settings..I'm unable to view the page! I'm getting redirected to the Facebook homepage

Comment: Maybe because you're outside of the UK, anyway I deleted the filter, now you should be able to see the page.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem, The coding and everything was fine, just I needed to create a username for the page,, so the address of the page changed to:
https://www.facebook.com/AlexaSalon

And when added the new address in the code creator, it worked.